# Redirect Apache Folder internally

Tags: apache, http, url-rewriting

i'm building a API Interface for a application that does perform a curl request (POST) to my server at https://myadomain.com/save.
My script is located in https://myadomain.com/save/ as index.php. The problem is now that the Apache Server is redirecting all requests with the target https://myadomain.com/save to https://myadomain.com/save/ (HTTP 301 Status Code), which the curl script on the other side is not following. I can't influence the curl script but how can i achieve that the Apache is serving my index.php script with a 200 Status Code on https://myadomain.com/save ?

Thanks

Comment: Please show the community what you have so far for your rewriting script. It helps to understand the problem and finding a specific solution.

Comment: I tried for example:
`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule "^/save$" "/save/"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to turn off DirectorySlash, but the trailing slash is rather important and it is there for a reason.

[Mod_dir docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash):

> Turning off the trailing slash redirect may result in an information disclosure. Consider a situation where mod_autoindex is active `(Options +Indexes)` and `DirectoryIndex` is set to a valid resource (say, `index.html`) and there's no other special handler defined for that URL. In this case a request with a trailing slash would show the `index.html` file.**But a request without trailing slash would list the directory contents.**

If you want to remove the directory slash, you have to make sure to rewrite the trailing slash back in internally.

```
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^save/(.*)$ save/index.php [L]
```

Comment: I did not know this. Good info. +1